# SQL distinct and count for a column in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, multiple-tables

So what I want is to have a table of `distinct` values and the `count` for those values.  basically I want it to look like this:

```
DistinctValue | Count
Bob           |   4
Fred          |   5
George        |   2
Joeseph       |   1
```

for a single table I use :

```
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) from TableName  group by Column
```

How would I do this so that it would span across multiple tables.  I have about say 30, possibly more, tables I need to do this for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if there's more information you need.  Oh, and there's no worry about the column name because all the tables have the same column name.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2 for one Database and Sql Server 2012 for another.

Comment: Is it the same column name in all tables?

Comment: @DMason Yes it's the same column name in all tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH mytbl AS (
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) AS myCount from TableName  group by Column
UNION ALL 
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) from TableName2  group by Column
... a union all for every table
)

SELECT ColumnName, SUM(myCount)
FROM mytbl
GROUP BY ColumnName
```

-- If you are using an earlier version of MS SQL, the UNION statements can be put in a big sub select or a table variable.
-- IE, they'd take the place of mytbl in the last query replace mytbl in the bottom query with the UNIONS from the CTE

Comment: "*an earlier version of SQL*" - SQL is a query language, it's **not** a DBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t.name,
    count(c.name) as columnsname
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    inner join sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
group by t.name
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following what this is doing.  Would you briefly explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create and execute dynamic tsql to get your results:

```
DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @ColumnName SYSNAME = 'YourColumnName'

SELECT @Tsql = @Tsql + 'SELECT ''[' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + ']'' AS TableName, ' +
    '[' + @ColumnName + '], COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM [' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + '] GROUP BY [' + @ColumnName + '] UNION ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
    --Comment out the next line if you want data/counts for views too. 
    AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName

--Remove the last UNION (and carriage-return, line-feed)
SELECT @Tsql = LEFT(@Tsql, LEN(@Tsql) - 8)

--Verify query.
PRINT @Tsql

--Uncomment when ready to proceed.
--EXEC (@Tsql)
```